# Orange Pi Zero: Wrong Date and Time even given Internet Access

Tags: linux, armbian

I am using Orange Pi Zero and running Armbian Stretch OS 5.59 on it.

Problem is, it is giving wrong date and time even in the presence of the Internet. I have tried restarting "ntp" service but to no avail. I have also tried rebooting, but the same annoying result. I have already set the right timezone which is PKT, but it shouldn't matter. So what do I need to do or change?

Thank you.

Comment: Please define what wrong time is and what commands/configurations you have done to try to fix it. If it should not matter, why talking about it, then? I recommend being consistent.

Comment: It showed time from September when I executed the "date" command. I tried the solutions above that I believed would relieve the problem, but no.

Comment: Does it run `ntpdate` or similar to step the time before starting `ntpd`?

Comment: Unit ntpdate.service could not be found.
The above is the response to "service ntpdate status". So, I assume there is no such service running in my system.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I have resolved the problem, I want to share it with others. I had to make changes in "/etc/resolv.conf". Here nameserver field stated "127.0.0.1", I changed it to google nameserver "8.8.8.8". The problem resolved and I have correct date and time now.

But now that I see again, "/etc/resolv.conf" has been overwritten by OS(I believe) and it again displays "127.0.0.1" as my nameserver. But, still I am getting the right date and time. My take is, I needed to coordinate with Google to update correct date and time. But upon reboot, OS retraces any changes made in "/etc/resolv.conf" but changes stick.

Comment: Related: [What overwrites /etc/resolv.conf on every boot?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/174349)

Comment: You seem to be talking about two related problems, and the question being a symptom of a related problem and not a cause per se.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro they are not related, I think. Because when I was about to edit "resolv.conf", it was written exclusively that my changes could be retraced.

Comment: @Kusalananda, I meant Operating System; Armbian in this case.

Comment: I believe I was at fault with this approach. Can I ask what service is responsible for updating date and time when internet access is available in Armbian?

Comment: NTP service might be pointing by default to NTP name servers referenced by DNS name. So if the DNS service is not working ok.-....